# React: What is the best way on implementing a server sided SSO login?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-hooks, single-sign-on

I'm creating a simple sso login react project with python as my backend server and reactJS as my frontend. I'm using react-google-login as my SSO login button. I've already setup my backend server which receives information from the google api and verifies the Token ID from it. My react app's logged in state will depend on an api call to the backend which verifies the posted Token ID, this runs everytime the app is rendered.
My problem is that everytime I render my app when logged in state is true, my login page shows for a brief second then continues on the home page. I've realized that it is because i'm using useState for the variable that defines if the logged in state of my app is true or false.

Here's my App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div id="routes">  
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<SearchBar/>}/>
            <Route path="/searched" element={<Table/>}/>
            <Route path="/tablecomponent" element={<AntdTable/>}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProtectedRoutes.js

```
const useAuth = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          try {
            const resp = await axios.get("/@me");
            setUsers(resp.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("Not authenticated");
          }
        })();
      }, []);
  const user = { loggedIn: users!=null };
  return user && user.loggedIn;
};

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const isAuth = useAuth();
  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Login/>;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Login.js

```
export default function Login() {
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const [tokenID, setTokenID] = useState(null)
    const clientId = "client_id"
    const onLoginSuccess = (res) =>{
        console.log("Login Success:", res);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            window.location.reload()
        },1000)
        try{fetch('/verifytoken',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
              token: res.tokenId,
              email: res.profileObj.email,
            }), headers:{"Content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
          }).then(response => response.json()).then(message=>console.log(message))
        }
          catch(error){
              alert(error)
          }   
    }
    const onLoginFailure = (res)=>{
        console.log("Login Failed:", res)
    }
    return (
        <div>
             Login Page <br/>
            <Link to="/">
                <button>button</button>
            </Link>
            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={onLoginSuccess}
                onFailure={onLoginFailure}
                cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you have to verify with the server every single time page is loaded to check if a user is logged in, you will run into this issue. I'd suggest storing an authenticated user's state as a JWT on the client side, and check that instead: then it is instantly available at runtime. You can then revoke the JWT on a rolling basis, e.g. after it expires, or when the user logs out.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for the suggestion! I'll check it out. I should have mentioned I am using flask session in my python server which stores information thrown by the client into a cookie. the logged in state of my app depends on this cookie if it's existing or not